# How to change order by in get_categories() function through advance custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I am trying to change order of listing categories. i am using get_categories() wp function i am passing custom field slug called order_by in meta key and set orderby value as meta_value_num  just but its showing blank array in it Please help or just let me know is this method is valid with  get_categories() or not

```
$args5 = array(
       'taxonomy'    => $taxonomies[0],
        'meta_key'   => 'order_by',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'parent' => 'enter code here0',
        'show_count' => true,
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'pad_counts' => true,);

 $categories = get_categories($args5);
 echo "<pre>";
print_R($categories);
```

Comment: Start by reading the [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) documentation (`get_categories` is an alias of this).

Comment: is `print_R` a typo?

Comment: its php function to print array